# How to draw N random samples from a vector in R?

Tags: r, random, permutation, sampling

I have a vector with 663 elements. I would like to create random samples from the vector equal to the length of the vector (i.e. 663). Said differently, I would like to take random samples from all possible orderings of the 663 elements. My goal is to create a data frame of the N random samples or randomly selected permutations.

I have tried the following:

```
library(combinat)
perms <- as.data.frame(permn(1:663))
```

Since there are so many possible permutations, I would receive an error message.

My next idea would be to create a data frame with as many rows as I would like samples/permutations and as many variables as elements (i.e. 663) and use a function like `sapply()` with `sample()`. However, I don't think this approach is that efficient.

I have also tried:

```
samples <- replicate(100, table(sample(1:663, 663,replace = F)))
```

but I just get a data frame with 100 columns of ones.

Comment: Because you are taking the `table`.  The frequency is just 1 as you are using `replace=FALSE`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`replicate` will work

```
a <- 1:663 #vector of 663 elements
perms <- as.data.frame(replicate(100, sample(a)))
```